# Is sentence "The artist I studied their art from is (name of the artist)..." correct?

Tags: ambiguity, prepositional-phrases

And if it's grammatically correct, does it have ambiguity to it? If so, how to rephrase this sentence to get rid of this ambiguity?

Comment: See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Not ambiguous, but a clumsy way of expressing the idea. It would be better to say "The artist whose art I studied..." or, to avoid repetition, "whose work I studied".

Comment: Do you mean *the artist whose art I studied* or *the artist who taught me their art*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems. Ways to express the idea of studying someone's art:

"I studied the art of Pablo Picasso."

"The artist whose art I studied is Pablo Picasso (or, to invert the sentence, "Pablo Picasso is the artist whose art I studied").

Your example needs to have the pronoun "whose" and the word order needs to be changed, or just simplify it as, "I studied the art of Picasso."

It is not common to use the phrase "studied from" someone.

Comment: It is "from", and to clarify here's an example:
"The artist I studied from is Picasso" reads clearly, but injecting "their art" between "from and "Picasso" makes it confusing.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the phrase "studied from." It's not common to say "I studied from someone." If the someone was your teacher, then you say you studied "with" him. If you studied his art, you say you "studied him" or "studied his work," but not "from" his work. Hope that helps.